# How do I retreve values from a json file?

Tags: php, json

I am trying to retrieve values from a well formed json file which has the values in multidimensional arrays. Weather forecasts in my case.

Here is the sample of the files I am working on. [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/KRNqFRXi) (My apologies, the file is to long to paste here).

Here is the code I used, but it's returning absolutely nothing.

```
<?php   
// Get Forecasts
$json_string = file_get_contents("http://weather.mailchips.com/weather.json");
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
$forecasts = $parsed_json->{'forecast'}->{'txt_forecast'}->{'forecastday'};

foreach ($forecasts as $forecast) { ?>
<div class="eachforecast">
<div class="fcday"><?php echo $forecast->{'title'};?></div>
<div class="fcicon"><?php echo $forecast->{'icon_url'};?></div>
<div class="fctext"><?php echo $forecast->{'fcttext_metric'};?></div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Please help me out. My knowledge in php isn't sufficiant to make this work.
Thanks

Comment: code works fine for me. check if you have allow_url_fopen setting in php to on. Try adding `echo $json_string;` to see if json is taken correctly from server

Comment: Why are you using `$parsed_json->{'forecast'}`? this should work: `$parsed_json->forecast` if the field is available.

Comment: @JerzyZawadzki Yes, the code suddenly started to work. Thanks Nicky De Maeyer, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Tip: if you pass `json_decode` `true` as the second parameter, it returns a multi-dimensional associative array instead of objects. I find that easier to work with.

Answer (score 2):

This is working as expected at my end :

```
<?php
$content=file_get_contents('http://weather.mailchips.com/weather.json');
$content= json_decode($content);
foreach($content->forecast->txt_forecast->forecastday as $day){
?>
<div class="eachforecast" style=" width:120px;border:1px solid gray;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;height:150px;overflow:auto">
    <div class="fcday"><?php echo $day->title;?></div>
    <div class="fcicon"><img src="<?php echo $day->icon_url;?>"></div>
    <div class="fctext"><?php echo $day->fcttext_metric;?></div>
</div>
<?php   
}
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Code works fine on my end.

But I am not sure why you're doing `$parsed_json->{'forecast'}` instead of `$parsed_json->forecast` for accessing the property values. Your method works, but its just ugly and inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

The piece of code you've given works absolutely fine.
You should check if `file_get_contents()` is allowed to access the URL.

You can do so by checking if `allow_url_fopen` is set to 1 in your php.ini.